# Disable "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" for all profiles(Domain,Public,Standard) in local GP using script help! Windows 7 Clients

Tags: windows-7, scripting, windows-firewall, windows-registry, vbscript

We need Windows7 with  windows firewall to be turned off , so the GOLD image has windows firewall turned off for all profiles(Domain,Public,Standard) and Windows Service disabled

No the same GOLD image deployed with MDT (Apply local GPO) has enabled Windows Firewall under "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" as part of task sequence

Now we need to remove it.

"These machines are now on Domain where in we have no rights/control on the domain level GPO", we have local admi rights on these machines

We have a requirement do set the "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" to "NOT Configured" or "OFF "on these machines

In gpedit.msc if we manually go to "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" after enabling Windows Firewall Services 
then can Clear the settings
Do do the same manually on all machines is extra effort

Changing values in registry will get reverted on machine restart as its getting applied from local GPO

Also using GPMC can connect to remote computer and can manually or using wfw file we can make it not configured

but we are looking for a script or a less effort method to accomplish this

Please suggest
NB:
CIA has already reported similar issue//How do I turn off Windows 7 Firewall via script or through automation?// , but doing netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off on already deployed machines did not make change (FW service on all machine is disabled in GOLd image)//

Thanks and Regards
Jose

Comment: It looks like there's a conflict of interest here. You're the local Administrator of the machine and want the firewall disabled but the people that manage the Domain that these computers are joined to want the firewall enabled. Perhaps the two of you should talk and work toward a mutually agreeable resolution.

Comment: Thank you Joe, even the domain admins want the FW to be disabled..and in domain GP its set as not configured..the local policy we need FW to be turned off or set as not configured under Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" in gpedit.msc which was set by MDT

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by removing the Registry.pol file from---

C:\Windows\system32\GroupPolicy\Machine

On removing this file and a restart (not always needed) removed the local policy set my MDT Under  “Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" and made it as not configured

May be we can just edit th Firewall part alone from Rgistry.pol file using some special tools
as direct editing the file in a normal editor like notepad causes corruption to the file.

Thanks and Regards
JoBo